# How to embed a submit form within link?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

In the following code, I would like to change the value of `data-filter` to a user-submitted field, and then, incorporate that input into the link.

```
<a href="#" id="gallery_filter" class="sidebar-search"
     data-filter="(get user input here)">
```

So far I've tried ajax objects, jquery mobile filters and regular HTML. I've tried about 20 different approaches, the most recent with jQuery mobile filters.

```
  <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search tags..." data-inset="true">
                                    <!-- foreach $tags as $tag [get all tags loop] -->
                                    <li><a href="#">$tag[0]</a></li>
                               </ul>
```

Comment: Can you post code you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you want to modify the DOM (in your case, a link), based on user input. If that's the case, you don't have to submit the form and you should basically take a straightforward approach, using simple jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var input_el = $("#user_input");
    var link_el = $("#link");

    input_el.keyup(function() {
        var value = input_el.val();
        link_el.attr('data-filter', value);
    });
});
```

You can see this in action here, in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/4bBSF/

However, if you really have to submit a form, you can also add a function to be executed onsubmit:

```
<form onsubmit="updateLink()"> ... </form>
```

onsubmit functions are executed before the form is sent. Then the `updateLink` function would do something similar to the example above, adding the value of the input to the link.

Now, if you really want to go further and try something fancy, read about data-binding. There are a bunch of libraries and frameworks supporting data binding, including [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/), [Ember](http://emberjs.com/) and [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/).

Comment: That looks great. I'm a little confused how to implement it. What I'm trying to modify is the 'data-filter' attribute. The link already has an ID 'gallery-filter' that does some kind of sorting function.